# Generating dynamic call graph of c/c++ programs on the run

Tags: c++, c, call-graph

If one were to visualize the running of a program, I suppose one would start by getting the call graphs of the program.

But how would you get the call graph of c/c++ programs while on the run?

**edit**: clarifications, I'm currently running things on linux, using g++, but I suppose I am also curious about solutions if I'm using a different platform.

Comment: Try [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or [Gprof](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/gprof/index.html)

Comment: +1 for helping Dr Kimble get his call graphs.

Comment: @kamziro: Why do you need *Runtime* call graphs? There are tools which can give you the callgraph by looking up from the code.

Comment: @Als: One possibility is that depending on the input, not all code paths are executed.  You may be interested in the calls made for a particular input vector.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: But an code analysis tool like Doxygen used with Graphviz will generate the graphs nicely, while it is rare that an runtime tool will be available as open source.

Comment: @Als: oprofile, [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial), callgrind to name a few

Comment: @sehe: Yes, I had look that up myself & posted one as an answer.

Comment: Which system, and which compiler ?

Comment: @Als: I want to visualize the actual program running, hence the runtime call graph. That is, I want to see the nodes making links to other nodes (function calls) happen in real time, or rather, slo-mo.

Comment: @Als: Doxygen doesn't seem to be able to resolve call targets when there is any kind of overloading.  I don't see how it can, considering it doesn't have a real C++ parser, and it doesn't really understand C++ lookup rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used [etrace](http://ndevilla.free.fr/etrace/) to trace executions of programs.

[Egypt](http://www.gson.org/egypt/egypt.html) does the same thing, but only has a limited support for C++.

Both requires the program to be instrumented with gcc.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[KCachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/show.cgi)** to generate and analyze call graphs based on data generated by **[Valgrind's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind)** callgrind tool.

Answer (score 1):

The **[Bug Validator](http://www.softwareverify.com/cpp-flow-tracer.php)** from SofwareVerify (free public beta available) does this.

Excerpt from homepage:

> C++ Bug Validator provides automatic execution history logging of applications as they run. There is **no need to recompile or relink your application**. C++ Bug Validator works with debug information and/or MAP files. C++ Bug Validator allows you to perform execution history logging on your entire application, or on just the DLLs you require.

(Markup from me).

I don't know *how* they do it, but obviously, it's possible.